# Device tree problem with Android Things 1.0.4

Tags: linux-kernel, android-things

We've been developing a product based on the Android Things OS, and to date have been prototyping with Android Things 0.7.0. Android Things ships with a few stock pre-built images based on your hardware platform containing embedded linux kernel device trees.

Up through Android Things version 0.7.0, we were able to unpack the Android boot image - boot.img - into it's various components using Android Image Kitchen. One of these components is boot.img-second, and it contained the compiled device tree blob. We then would use the linux tool Device Tree Compiler to decompile the blob into an editable dts file, where we could modify the appropriate settings (lcd display timings in this case), then recompile the dtb file, replace the original in the unpacked boot image, then repack the boot image, and finally flash the device.

This all worked perfectly, until the recently released Android Things 1.0. We are now attempting to deploy 1.0.4, and now need to modify the stock device tree to accommodate our hardware, however, when unpacking the supplied boot.img file, the device tree file (boot.img-second) seems to be  missing. Any suggestions on where to find the device tree, and how we can modify it to accept our hardware would be greatly appreciated. Below are screen captures of the unpacked boot images from Android Things 0.7.0 and then the newer 1.0.4.

[image]